# Is there a kind of Wordreference website for Esperanto?

Tags: translation, websites

[Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/) is a very good website to find translation of words between many languages but Esperanto is missing.

I would like to know if there is a website where I can find an equivalent service to translate words from Esperanto to English and vice-versa.

Comment: You might like to take a look at this related question https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/199/which-are-the-best-multilingual-online-and-offline-dictionaries

Comment: Links: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/ and http://kono.be/vivo/ - not so slick as Wordreference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it’s not a website, for English-Esperanto I highly recommend John Wells’ dictionary. It is available on [paper from Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/English-Esperanto-English-Dictionary-2010-Christopher-Wells/dp/1595691499/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1472137222&sr=8-10&keywords=esperanto) or even as an [eBook on SmashWords](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176). If you get the ebook version you can keep it on your phone or your laptop and it’s almost as convenient as WordReference for looking up words.

Otherwise there is the [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) which is a dictionary that has translations into many languages. However the translations are more useful just to understand the meaning of the Esperanto word and it doesn’t really have enough words to be useful to look up a word in the other direction.

There is also a good multi-lingual dictionary on [Lernu](https://lernu.net/en/vortaro).

Comment: "If you press Alt+1"? What do you mean?

Comment: @Pierre The dictionary is hidden behind a little book icon in the top-left corner of the website. There is also a shortcut key “Alt+1” to open it. I thought the shortcut was easier to explain than the icon. I guess I was wrong :p

Comment: Also it seems you have to log in before it will let you see the dictionary in this new version of the site. (They changed it a lot recently to make it look more modern and quite a few people are upset about it).

Comment: Or you can directly access to the dictionnary here: https://lernu.net/fr/vortaro (no log required).

Comment: @Pierre Oh, good tip! I will change the link in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Wikitionary: https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do.
It is an esperanto dictionary, but it is in esperanto. It has a tranlations section at the bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wiktionary is not enough complete. For instance, I was searching the translation of a very simple word "pura" and the page doesn't exist.